# Are all constant fields conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, constants

Are all constant fields conservative? Can there be some constant vector fields which are not conservative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. A conservative field is a vector field which is the gradient of some function. So, if $\mathbf v$ is a constant vector field, that is $\mathbf{v}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, you can take$$F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n.$$Then $\mathbf{v}=\nabla F$.

Comment: I do not understand what $x_1$ and $a_1$ means? Can you please give a proof of it in three dimensions, so that a high school student (like me) can understand easily?

Comment: @Joe If you want a $3$-dimensional proof, just take $n=3$. You wrote that $\mathbf v$ is constant and so I took $\mathbf{v}(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$. Then $\mathbf{v}=\nabla f$, where $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$.

Comment: Thanks.... I understand.

Comment: @Joe I'm glad I could help.